# Передача сообщения об ошибке в контроллер

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, mvc, try-catch

Не могу разобраться, как передать сообщение об исключении в вид. Поясню: в модели у меня есть код типа:

```
class Ex{
    public function Example(){
        try{
            //тут идет выполнение операции
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне передать сообщение об ошибке в контроллер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вид или контроллер?
Если в контроллер то не надо его перехватывать:

```
//Model
class Ex{
   public function Example(){
    //тут идет выполнение операции
  }
}
```

.

```
//Controller
class MyController{
    function execute(){
        $model = null;
        try{
            $ex = new \Ex();
            $model = $ex::Example();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            //Вот здесь вы и получите сообщение в контроллере
            //$e->getMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

А если в вид, то зависит от движка/фреймворка или шаблонизатора.

Comment: В итоге, мне нужно сообщение вывести в виде. Фреймворк Yii2.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.